# C# HttpWebRequest request through proxy

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webproxy

I'm trying to make my program work through proxy but it doesn't want to (System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out). 
Without proxy everything is fine

Here is a code:

```
        string proxy = "154.46.33.157";
        int port = 8080;
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "email=" + email + "&pass=" + pass;
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(proxy, port);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("SITE");
        WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
        request.CookieContainer = sCookie;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Proxy = myproxy;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Host = "HOST";
        request.UserAgent = "[UA]";
        request.Referer = "reffer";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = 20000;

        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream(); // TIMEOUT HERE
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();
        request.GetResponse()
            .Close();
```

at the same time this code works well

```
        string proxy = "154.46.33.157";
        int port = 8080;
        WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(proxy, port);
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("SITE");
        req.Timeout = 5000;
        req.GetResponse();
```

proxy is alive, i've tested it via IE. What should i do to fix it?

Comment: Be careful hard-coding things... **ESPECIALLY** IP addresses. This is what configuration files are for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few suggestions:

1. do you use IP address for the proxy?
2. do you need to log in to that proxy?
   proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(User, Password);
3. try less headers, start with few and if it works keep adding one by one

UPD:
for the host - is it a valid URL? Did you put a valid port number?
like www.contoso.com:8080

Comment: i dont need to log in. And ty for headers advice, i'll try

Comment: TY it helped. But now I have an another problem. requst.Host does not work with proxy, but I need it to send my POST request

Comment: Very good advice on headers. I solved my problem by removing headers like "User-Agent"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following into either your `web.config` or `app.config` depending on application type:

```
<configuration>

    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy>
            <proxy
                usesystemdefaults="true"
                proxyaddress="http://154.46.33.157:8080"
                bypassonlocal="true" />
              <bypasslist
                <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com" />
            </bypasslist>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>          

     <!-- The rest of your config here ... -->

</configuration>
```

You can find more details and additional parameters such as user credentials etc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: dude, he want to change the proxy in Runtime

Comment: Why do you say that? Where in the question does he say that? His question is how to get through proxy, nothing about changing at runtime. Why would you change at runtime as it is unlikely a proxy would move half-way through running! :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Really I want to change it in runtime

Comment: Why would you change it at runtime? Under what circumstances would you need to change it?

Comment: May "runtime" means "configureable from the user at runtime"? So just "changeable" :-)